# crawling [own] webpage for 404s

Tags: untagged

can you suggest linux tool that can crawl given page in search of 404s?

yes - i can use wget in recursive mode or just watch access logs but maybe you have hints for better suited tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [linkchecker](http://linkchecker.sourceforge.net/)? Another good one is oldie but goldie [ht://Check](http://htcheck.sourceforge.net/).